Procedurally generated Pathways for my Procedurally Generated Terrain (Tower Defense Game)
I'm working on the procedural terrain generation for my tower defense game. I have created the generated mesh and it works with height variation etc, but I'm trying to procedurally generate the pathways for my enemies to travel along towards the player's tower, and it's not working.
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
public class MeshGeneratorV1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    Mesh mesh;
    private int MESH_SCALE = 500;
    public AnimationCurve heightCurve;
    private Vector3[] vertices;
    private int[] triangles;

    public int xSize;
    public int zSize;

    public float scale;
    public int octaves;
    public float lacunarity;

    public int seed;
    private System.Random prng;
    private Vector2[] octaveOffsets;

    void Start()
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
        CreateNewMap();
    }

    public void CreateNewMap()
    {
        CreateMeshShape();
        CreateTriangles();
        UpdateMesh();
    }

    private void CreateMeshShape()
    {
        Vector2[] octaveOffsets = GetOffsetSeed();

        if (scale <= 0)
            scale = 0.0001f;

        vertices = new Vector3[(xSize + 1) * (zSize + 1)];

        List<Vector3Int> outerSquares = GetOuterSquares();
        Vector3Int center = GetCenterSquare();

        foreach (var start in outerSquares)
        {
            List<Vector3Int> path = FindPath(start, center);

            foreach (var point in path)
            {
                // Flatten the path; adjust the height as needed
                vertices[point.z * (xSize + 1) + point.x] = new Vector3(point.x, 0, point.z);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zSize; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
            {
               /*
                if (vertices[i].y == 0)
                {
                    i++;
                    continue; // Skip path vertices
                }
               */
                float noiseHeight = GenerateNoiseHeight(z, x, octaveOffsets);
                vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, noiseHeight, z);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    private Vector2[] GetOffsetSeed()
    {
        seed = Random.Range(0, 1000);
        System.Random prng = new System.Random(seed);
        Vector2[] octaveOffsets = new Vector2[octaves];

        for (int o = 0; o < octaves; o++)
        {
            float offsetX = prng.Next(-100000, 100000);
            float offsetY = prng.Next(-100000, 100000);
            octaveOffsets[o] = new Vector2(offsetX, offsetY);
        }
        return octaveOffsets;
    }

    private float GenerateNoiseHeight(int z, int x, Vector2[] octaveOffsets)
    {
        float amplitude = 12;
        float frequency = 1;
        float persistence = 0.5f;
        float noiseHeight = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < octaves; y++)
        {
            float mapZ = z / scale * frequency + octaveOffsets[y].y;
            float mapX = x / scale * frequency + octaveOffsets[y].x;

            float perlinValue = (Mathf.PerlinNoise(mapZ, mapX)) * 2 - 1;
            noiseHeight += heightCurve.Evaluate(perlinValue) * amplitude;
            frequency *= lacunarity;
            amplitude *= persistence;
        }
        return noiseHeight;
    }

    private void CreateTriangles()
    {
        triangles = new int[xSize * zSize * 6];
        int vert = 0;
        int tris = 0;

        for (int z = 0; z < xSize; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
            {
                triangles[tris + 0] = vert + 0;
                triangles[tris + 1] = vert + xSize + 1;
                triangles[tris + 2] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 3] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 4] = vert + xSize + 1;
                triangles[tris + 5] = vert + xSize + 2;

                vert++;
                tris += 6;
            }
            vert++;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateMesh()
    {
        mesh.Clear();
        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        mesh.RecalculateTangents();
        GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = mesh;

        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(MESH_SCALE, MESH_SCALE, MESH_SCALE);
    }

    private List<Vector3Int> GetOuterSquares()
    {
        List<Vector3Int> outerSquares = new List<Vector3Int>();

        for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
        {
            outerSquares.Add(new Vector3Int(x, 0, 0));       // Bottom edge
            outerSquares.Add(new Vector3Int(x, 0, zSize));   // Top edge
        }

        for (int z = 1; z < zSize; z++)
        {
            outerSquares.Add(new Vector3Int(0, 0, z));       // Left edge
            outerSquares.Add(new Vector3Int(xSize, 0, z));   // Right edge
        }

        return outerSquares;
    }

    private Vector3Int GetCenterSquare()
    {
        return new Vector3Int(xSize / 2, 0, zSize / 2);
    }

    private List<Vector3Int> FindPath(Vector3Int start, Vector3Int target)
    {
        List<Vector3Int> openList = new List<Vector3Int>();
        HashSet<Vector3Int> closedList = new HashSet<Vector3Int>();
        Dictionary<Vector3Int, Vector3Int> cameFrom = new Dictionary<Vector3Int, Vector3Int>();

        openList.Add(start);

        while (openList.Count > 0)
        {
            Vector3Int current = openList[0];
            openList.RemoveAt(0);

            if (current == target)
                return ReconstructPath(cameFrom, current);

            closedList.Add(current);

            foreach (Vector3Int neighbor in GetNeighbors(current))
            {
                if (closedList.Contains(neighbor)) continue;

                if (!openList.Contains(neighbor))
                {
                    openList.Add(neighbor);
                    cameFrom[neighbor] = current;
                }
            }
        }

        return new List<Vector3Int>(); // Return empty if no path found
    }

    private List<Vector3Int> ReconstructPath(Dictionary<Vector3Int, Vector3Int> cameFrom, Vector3Int current)
    {
        List<Vector3Int> totalPath = new List<Vector3Int> { current };
        while (cameFrom.ContainsKey(current))
        {
            current = cameFrom[current];
            totalPath.Insert(0, current);
        }
        return totalPath;
    }

    private List<Vector3Int> GetNeighbors(Vector3Int node)
    {
        List<Vector3Int> neighbors = new List<Vector3Int>();

        if (node.x > 0) neighbors.Add(new Vector3Int(node.x - 1, 0, node.z)); // Left
        if (node.x < xSize) neighbors.Add(new Vector3Int(node.x + 1, 0, node.z)); // Right
        if (node.z > 0) neighbors.Add(new Vector3Int(node.x, 0, node.z - 1)); // Down
        if (node.z < zSize) neighbors.Add(new Vector3Int(node.x, 0, node.z + 1)); // Up

        return neighbors;
    }
}



This is my mesh Generation script I have implemented the pathway creation code into it. When i implemented this my mesh generated and it was completely flat, with now height variation. and it turns out the if statement i commented out was the reason for that issue, but i still have no idea how to create the pathways. I hope this is understandable for you to help me please. If you still need more information please let me now.

You first do:
vertices = new Vector3[(xSize + 1) * (zSize + 1)];

which results in all vertices having y = 0.
Then you do:
foreach (var start in outerSquares)
{
    List<Vector3Int> path = FindPath(start, center);

    foreach (var point in path)
    {
        // Flatten the path; adjust the height as needed
        vertices[point.z * (xSize + 1) + point.x] = new Vector3(point.x, 0, point.z);
    }
}

which sets y = 0 for all vertices again. It does it for all vertices because you generate paths from every outer sqaure to the center which results in all the mesh covered.
Then here:
for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zSize; z++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
    {
        if (vertices[i].y == 0)
        {
            i++;
            continue; // Skip path vertices
        }

        float noiseHeight = GenerateNoiseHeight(z, x, octaveOffsets);
        vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, noiseHeight, z);
        i++;
    }
}

you check every vertex for having y = 0, which is always true, because all your vertices were set to 0 previously. And because of that you never apply the noise and your mesh is always flat.
In order to fix that, you need to remove this code (that you already commented out):
if (vertices[i].y == 0)
{
    i++;
    continue; // Skip path vertices
}

Then put
for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zSize; z++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
    {
        ...
    }
}

before
foreach (var start in outerSquares)
{
    ...
}

And then you need to adjust your paths creation. But for now you can simply put break after inner foreach to see a single path generated:
foreach (var start in outerSquares)
{
    List<Vector3Int> path = FindPath(start, center);

    foreach (var point in path)
    {
        // Flatten the path; adjust the height as needed
        vertices[point.z * (xSize + 1) + point.x] = new Vector3(point.x, 0, point.z);
    }

    break;
}

Part of your mesh could be  flat, so in order to see the path you can temporarily increase the default height of your vertices by adding a constant, e.g.:
vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, noiseHeight + 3, z);


So in the end your CreateMeshShape should look like this:
private void CreateMeshShape()
{
    Vector2[] octaveOffsets = GetOffsetSeed();

    if (scale <= 0)
        scale = 0.0001f;

    vertices = new Vector3[(xSize + 1) * (zSize + 1)];

    List<Vector3Int> outerSquares = GetOuterSquares();
    Vector3Int center = GetCenterSquare();

    for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zSize; z++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
        {
            float noiseHeight = GenerateNoiseHeight(z, x, octaveOffsets);
            vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, noiseHeight + 3, z);
            i++;
        }
    }

    foreach (var start in outerSquares)
    {
        List<Vector3Int> path = FindPath(start, center);

        foreach (var point in path)
        {
            // Flatten the path; adjust the height as needed
            vertices[point.z * (xSize + 1) + point.x] = new Vector3(point.x, 0, point.z);
        }

        break;
    }
}

With that, you should see a single path generated. Don't forget to remove break and + 3 when improving the algorithm.
